# How to validate request parameters in Spring REST controller

Tags: java, spring, validation, exception, spring-restcontroller

I am working on a Spring REST application.
This application has only REST controllers, no view part.
I want to know how can I validate a `@RequestParam`
**For example**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", params = "from", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<MealReadingDTO> getAllMealReadingsAfter(@RequestParam(name = "from", required = true) Date fromDate) {
......
......
}
```

In the above example, my goal is to validate the `Date`. Suppose someone pass an invalid value, then I should be able to handle that situation.
Now it is giving and exception with `500` status.
**PS**
My question is not just about `Date` validation.
Suppose, there is a `boolean` parameter and someone passes `tru` instead of `true` by mistake, I should be able to handle this situation as well.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: looks like you need to implement a custom validation

Comment: @MarcoAcierno how can I do that, can you provide me a link or something. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring will fail with an `500` status code, because it cannot parse the value.

The stages of request handling are:

1. receive request
2. identify endpoint
3. parse request params / body values and bind them to the detected objects
4. validate values if `@Validated` is used
5. enter method call with proper parameters

In your case the flow fails at the parse (3) phase.

Most probably you receive a `BindException`. 
You may handle these cases by providing an exception handler for your controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {
     @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
     @ResponseBody
     public YourErrorObject handleBindException(BindException e) {
         // the details which field binding went wrong are in the 
         // exception object. 
         return yourCustomErrorData;
     }
}
```

Otherwise when parsing is not functioning as expected (especially a hussle with `Date`s), you may want to add your custom mappers / serializers.

Most probably you have to configure Jackson, as that package is responsible for serializing / deserializing values.

Comment: Let me try this one, Thanks :)